# Буквы и их размеры

Tags: html, css, текст

Как добиться того, чтобы все буквы имели одинаковую ширину?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Моноширинный шрифт](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%88%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%82)

Можно тегами `<code>`, `<kbd>`, `<samp>`, можно в CSS универсальным семейством шрифтов `monospace`:

```css
.monospace-css {
    font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<H3>Обычный текст</H3>
<div class="plain">
  WWWWWWWW<br/>
  iiiiiiii<br/>
</div>
<H3>Моноширинный текст CSS</H3>
<div class="monospace-css">
  WWWWWWWW<br/>
  iiiiiiii<br/>
</div>
<H3>Моноширинный текст CODE</H3>
<code class="monospace-tag">
  WWWWWWWW<br/>
  iiiiiiii<br/>
</code>
<H3>Моноширинный текст KBD</H3>
<kbd class="monospace-tag">
  WWWWWWWW<br/>
  iiiiiiii<br/>
</kbd>
<H3>Моноширинный текст SAMP</H3>
<samp class="monospace-tag">
  WWWWWWWW<br/>
  iiiiiiii<br/>
</samp>
```